# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.？？？

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs-sdk

when i run to

```
 BranchHistoryTreeItem[][] TreeItem = vcs.GetBranchHistory(new ItemSpec[] { new                                     
 ItemSpec(teamProject.ServerItem, RecursionType.Full) }, LatestVersionSpec.Latest);
```

there are a issue "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." but  BranchHistoryTreeItem[][] has declared TreeItem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the `TreeItem` which is null, it could be `vcs` or `teamProject` which is null. Put a break point and hover over `vcs` or `teamProject` and see which is null.

Comment: VersionControlServer vcs =    (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

Comment: @user1536577, that can still be null

Comment: tfs isn't NULL,whai 's problem about  GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer))???

Comment: @user1536577, I am not sure, probably because you don't have any service of type VersionControlServer

Answer (score 0):

Your `vcs` **probabbly**  is Null or it's `teamProject`, don't see any other possibility.

Check it out.

Debug the program.